# aliasing in fortran with intent in

Tags: fortran

is it legal (or can it give trubles) to call a fortran subroutine with aliasing if the dummy variables are intent(IN)? I have to do something like this in my code:

```
  program myprogram
     ......
     ......
     call check(itstrt, itstrt )
     do k= itstrt,itend
        call check(itstrt, k)
     enddo
  end

  subroutine check(itstrt, k)
  integer , intent(in)    :: itstrt, k
     if(k==itstrt) write(*,*) 'I gotta do something'
  end
```

I know I can easily use an extra variable varPROV=itstrt  to call the first check as call check(itstrt, varPROV) but I d like to know what the standard says and which are the trouble of doing that.
thanks
A.

Comment: I don't understand what you think would be problematic, that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is legal.  The problem with aliasing and with `INTENT(IN)` (separately) relate to the program trying to define a dummy variable - perhaps by the variable appearing on the left hand side of an assignment statement or similar.

Comment: So if itstrt was intent(IN) and k intent(OUT), and if the subroutine contains k=1000., would that still be legal?

Comment: Cause here it says: "This kind of on-the-fly aliasing is permitted by the standard only when none of the aliased items are defined, or written, while the aliasing is in effect.)" "http://www.sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gcc-3.0.2/html_node/g77_561.html

Comment: No. It would not be legal.